# Data table js default date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need to change the default date format, since I have more than 1000 datatable instances, so dont want to change it in each instance, want to change its default date format rendering

I was trying to replace the text while rendering, I am trying following way

```
 $.fn.dataTable.render.text(function (data, type, row) {
        console.log('in')
        console.log(data)
        console.log(type)
        console.log(row)
    });
    $.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.render, {
        "text": function (a) {
            console.log(a)
        },
    });
```

I am trying to get the data, then I can check the data type and replace the date format and return new formatted data,

but none of above is calling when data table being rendered

I also tried

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment('dddd D MMMM YYYY');
```

but not effenct

Please help
Thanks

Comment: Please link to the library you're talking about

Comment: its jquery datatable

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript alone, try the following...

```
function formatEmptyDates(t) {
  if(t) {
    var monthNames = [
      "January", "February", "March",
      "April", "May", "June", "July",
      "August", "September", "October",
      "November", "December"
    ];

    var date = new Date(t);
    var day = date.getDate();
    var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
    var year = date.getFullYear();

    //console.log(day, monthNames[monthIndex], year);
    return day + ' ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year;
  } else {
    return 'Unknown';
  }
}
```

Then call it like this...

```
{
  "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
    return formatEmptyDates(row[5]);
  },
  "targets": 5
},
```

It might be valuable for empty rows as it is intended for, but you can easily adapt it for your needs.

Comment: I need to override the jquery datatable default date format

Comment: This line would do that [return day + ' ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year] you would just need to adjust to what you need to render?

Comment: I don't want to make changes at each tables, I have around 1000 jquery datatable, I want to override its default datetime format

Comment: That seems to be a different question? Do you mean you have a 1000 datatable instances, or 1000 rows of data?

Comment: 1000 datatable instances, that's why i asked to change datatable default setting

Comment: 14 hours later, sorry, was sleeping, lol. It would be best if you used the CDN (single source, more efficient) for all instances and just modify each implementation as described above. If so desired though, you would need to fork/download the repo and make modifications to the core, but be aware that means you will be maintaining your own custom version without support (maybe) - https://github.com/DataTables/DataTablesSrc